# How to create a variable that selects columns from a specific section of rows?

Tags: python, database, dataframe

`I am creating a dataframe that I can use to compare various metrics from Blast motion bat sensor and Rapsodo hitting. Blast motion provides info about the bat and its movement through space (Swing Data) and Rapsodo tracks the ball flight after contact (Exit Data). Both platforms have name tag identifiers that can distinguish individual players. All the swings are in one large data frame. How do i create a variable that will allow me to select a specific metric i.e (bat speed) but only from specific players?

http://localhost:8853/notebooks/Untitled1-Copy1.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

First, a `localhost` link is not very useful for most of us. Second, to select columns, you do `df[[col1, col2, ..., coln]]`. And if you want to select rows `1, 3, 17`, you do:

`df[[col1, col2, ..., coln]].iloc[[1, 3, 17]]`

Comment: Sorry very new to this forum and python in general. How would I share a link that is viewable by others?

Comment: @CollinMcBride if you put your notebook in the cloud, or on colab, or?!

Comment: @CollinMcBride sure.